# Append header in a vue axios request

Tags: django, axios, vuejs3

I have a django backend and a Vue 3 frontend.

For handling some request, my backend needs an 'Id-Client' header in the headers of the request.

Developing my BE everything worked like a charm, but now that I'm writing the FE I'm encountering some issues.

As I said before, I need to append an header to my headers in every request.
So the first step was the following:

```
// Note that the idClient is dynamic and can change.
this.$axios.setHeader('Id-Client', idClient)
const data = await this.$axios.$get(url)
```

But I can't get it to work, if I try to send that request, my GET request becomes (I don't know why) a OPTIONS request and I get the error "cross origin resource sharing error: HeaderDisallowedByPreflightResponse"

Instead if I remove the set header

```
// this.$axios.setHeader('Id-Client', idClient)
const data = await this.$axios.$get(url)
```

The server just respond me correctly giving me the error that the request is missing the 'Id-Client' in the header.

---

I also have a few request that don't need the 'Id-client' header and those request work, so I don't think is a CORS problem.

Comment: @MichalLevý thankyou for the reply, any idea how I can make it work?

Answer (score 0):

Well but is looks like CORS issue. CORS policies are not triggered by [simple requests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#simple_requests). By adding custom header, your requests are no longer *simple* and trigger CORS policies (sending OPTIONS before GET)

Your only option is to configure your backend server to reply to `OPTIONS` requests with the [correct headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#preflighted_requests) - `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` and `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` (server telling the browser "yes, im ok to accept particular custom header")

**IF (and only if)** you are planning to serve your Vue SPA from the same API server in production (same origin), you can avoid similar CORS issues during development by using [Webpack Dev server Proxy](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserverproxy) - your SPA will send API requests to Webpack Dev Server (used for developing SPA) and Proxy will route it to your Django dev server. That way all request from your SPA are to the same origin and you don't need to care about CORS at all...